# Serialize nullable fields from an object c#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, null

I am trying to serialize an object that has nullable fields.  If the field doesn't have any data in it the field is dropped from the serialized output.  Any suggests on how to work around this? Is there a way to specify that nullable empty fields still get carried over?

This occurs when "propertyname_specified = false"

Comment: I would like to suggest that you accept the answer that you like by clicking on the green check mark.  It will give positive feedback to the people that answered your question, and a way of saying "thank you for answering my question"

Comment: If the field is null, what did you expect to see in the XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must apply XmlElementAttribute:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string DummyField { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how nulls are communicated in .NET XML serialization, the element doesn't exist.